# How do I count the "role" instances in a cluster using RapidMiner

Tags: weka, rapidminer

I have a RapidMiner flow that takes a dataset and clusters it. In the output I can see my role, but I can't figure out a way to count the role per cluster. How can I count the number of roles per cluster. I've looked at the Aggregate node but my role isn't an available attribute.

Essentially, I'm trying to figure out if the clusters say anything about the role. I also use Weka and they call this "Classes to clusters evaluation". It basically shows how the class (or role) breakdown per cluster.

My current flow:
[image]

Only two attributes are available. My role isn't one of them.
[image]

There are 34 total attributes. I want to aggregate by ret_zpc
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by role in this context. I'm guessing you mean class. If so, do you want to count the number of times pairs of class labels and cluster values appear so you can see how the clusters map to labels?

Comment: Yes, I mean class. I've very new to Rapidminer but it seems to want to call class a role. Is that accurate? Yes, I want to see how often my class label appears in a cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RapidMiner has the concept of roles. An attribute can be one of regular, id, cluster or label (and some others). There's even an operator, `Set Role` that allows the role to be changed. Outside RapidMiner, role, label and class get used interchangeably.

For your question, the `Aggregate` operator is what you need. Assuming you have an attribute in your example set with role `Cluster` and another with role `Label` you select these attributes as the ones to group by. For aggregation attribute, choose another attribute and select count as the aggregation function.

In your case, the attributes you want are not being populated in the drop downs but they can still be used. You just have to type them in manually and explicitly add them to the selection criteria. This absence of attributes can sometimes happen if RapidMiner cannot see any metadata for the attributes. If you change the `Read CSV` operator so that it has an explicit mapping you should find that the attributes appear for selection.

Comment: What you're suggesting is what I've tried. I read from a CSV, set the role, normalize, and cluster. Then when I try to aggregate the role that I set isn't an available attribute, only the ID and cluster role are available. None of the other 30+ attributes are available.

Comment: Could you post a process that allows the problem to be reproduced? Some things however: set a breakpoint on the `Normalise` operator, what do you see in the example set? What are the settings of the `Set Role` operator?

Comment: Did you see the screenshots I added, I won't be able to share the data itself? The "Set Role" node sets my class attribute to a "target role" of "label". If I view the example set of the normalize node it's looks very similar to what the example set of the clustering node shows. All my attributes are there.

Comment: What shows up in the `group by` parameter of the `Aggregate` operator? What happens if you connect the output of the `Set Role` operator to the `Cluster` operator?

Comment: I've reduced the problem to a small csv and simple flow. It can be found here [link](http://www.filedropper.com/clustertest)

Comment: I updated the answer. The root cause is likely to be the `Read CSV` operator.